# Joining two tables and select records with where condition in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL, I got a requirement of joining two tables and get data for last 24 hours orders from both orders and books table joined on bookid. Below is the way I tried below solution ,Is this the right approach to write? please help thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test.books@state NVARCHAR(20) 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
b.orderid,a.bookid,b.date
FROM books a
INNER JOIN orders AS b  ON a.bookid= b.bookid
where b.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and a.author="JOHN"  
END
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code will not work in Oracle.  In fact, I don't think the code would work in any SQL dialects; it appears to be mixing functionality from at least two.

Comment: Are results correct? Join itself seems reasonable. I’d like to put authorname as procedure parameter.

Comment: Yes is right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a ref cursor to do this.  This ref cursor has to be picked out as a parameter by your application.

SYSDATE is the current date in Oracle (including the time).  SYSDATE - 1 is 24 hours prior.

Strings are single quoted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE Books(
                      p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_recordset FOR
    SELECT
b.orderid,a.bookid,b.date
FROM books a
INNER JOIN orders AS b  ON a.bookid= b.bookid
where b.date > SYSDATE-1 and a.author='JOHN'  ;
END Books
```

Comment: Thanks you ctznkane